# Multiple threads reading from ConcurrentLinkedQueue, and entry to DB. Not all entries are being written

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, try-catch

I have a method, that writes about 7 million entries to the queues.I'm reading the entries one by one, in multiple threads, and writing it to a DB. Here is the code snippet for the class that does it. 
Again, this is executing in a multithreading environment.

```
private class WriteRunner<T> implements Callable<Long> {

// member variables

public WriteRunner(ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> elementsQueue,...)
     //constructor
}

@Override
public Long call() throws Exception {

  while (!elementsQueue.isEmpty()) {
    int failures = 0;
    T t = elementsQueue.poll();
    while (true) {
      try {
        // write to DB
        break;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log error
        //Wait for 10 seconds and retry
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        if (++failures > 10) {
          throw new Exception(
              String.format("[TID: %d] Connection repeatedly failed.", threadId));
        }
      }
    }

  }

  //log more stuff
  return (long)total;
}
}
```

Here is how I'm calling the method

```
      for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
           completionService.submit(
             new WriteRunner<T>(elementsQueue ,...));
       }
       long total = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < N_THREADS; i++) {
            total += completionService.take().get();
       }
```

I'm missing as many entries, as there is the number of exceptions.
My idea is to, retry on the same 't' element that's the latest poll.

What is going wrong with the exceptions?

Comment: What's the cause of the exception? You should post the stacktrace here

Comment: Have you put `//Wait for 10 seconds and retry`  into a try/catch block?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn : Connection to DB timeout..

Comment: @ArtemPetrov Yes of course!

Comment: How do you connect to your DB? Connection pooling or direct open/close? YOu should show the minimal relevant code